# Is there a function for dropping so many rows of a dataframe so that only 10 rows are left?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a function that drops the last x rows of a dataframe, so that for example only 50 rows are left. The problem is that the number of rows varies every time I run my program, so I cannot use the the df.iloc[:3] funtion to drop the last 3 rows for example.

Example: My dataframe has 77 rows one time and 80 rows another time and I want to drop so many rows at the end that only 50 are left. What would be a function that can do that?

Thank you for your help!

Greetings,
Sara

Comment: D you mean `df.head(50)`?

Comment: On another note, `df.iloc[:3]` picks the **first three** rows, not drop the last three rows. And it would work even if your dataframe has less than three rows.

Comment: Don't try to drop any additional rows, think about **getting** the first 50 rows by either the `.head()` or `.iloc` method.